# How to delete or unblock an IP address listed in IPtables firewall?

Tags: server, iptables

I am trying to delete an IP address that appears listed on the server's IPtable.

I'm using the following command to list the IPs:

```
iptables -L INPUT -n --line-numbers
```

Giving me a result like:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    acctboth   all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    DROP       all  --  xxx.xx.xx.xx         0.0.0.0/0
```

**Question:**

How to delete or unblock the entry number two, listed as `xxx.xx.xx.xx` ?

Comment: `man iptables` whould give you all answers you wish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the number on the left, then use number to delete it. For example delete line number 2, enter:

```
iptables -D INPUT 2
```